# How to load a live image into a UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, live-wallpaper

I am trying to load a live image into a `UImageView` but it is being loaded as a static image.

Here is my code:

```
if let stringLocal = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Image_from _iOS", ofType: "jpg") {
    self.displayImageView.image = UIImage(named: stringLocal)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`PHLivePhoto`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phlivephoto) instead of `UIImageView`.

Specifically for loading you need to use [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phlivephoto/1616434-request)

```
request(withResourceFileURLs:placeholderImage:targetSize:contentMode:resultHandler:)
```

Comment: Also the format in the question is jpg. Pretty sure jpg doesn't contain the live photo data; would need to use HEIC.

Comment: is there any site where live wallpapers i can find, so that i can pull in into my app to show users.

Answer (score 1):

A live photo is a PHLivePhoto, not a UIImage. So it is displayed live in a PHLivePhotoView, not a UIImageView.